# C++ execution time for swapping two dimensional arrays

Tags: c++

Why does it matter which dimension is bigger, if it's stored as a vector anyway? I use such code and can't figure out why second part give bigger result time.

```
    #include <time.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <random>
    using namespace std;


    const int n=2000000,m=10;
    const int n1=10,m1=2000000;
    int a[n][m];
    int b[n][m];

    int aa[n1][m1];
    int bb[n1][m1];

    int main()
    {

        time_t start,end;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                a[i][j]=rand()%(m*n);
                b[i][j]=rand()%(m*n)+m*n;
            }
        start = clock(); // from here
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                int tmp = a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = b[i][j];
                b[i][j] = tmp;
            }

        end = clock(); // to here
        cout<<end-start<<endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < m1; j++)
            {
                aa[i][j]=rand()%(m1*n1);
                bb[i][j]=rand()%(m1*n1)+m1*n1;
            }
        start = clock(); // from here
        for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < m1; j++)
            {
                int tmp = aa[i][j];
                aa[i][j] = bb[i][j];
                bb[i][j] = tmp;
            }

        end = clock(); // to here
        cout<<end-start<<endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

I am getting ~69 for the first cout and ~172 for the second cout, while I expect them to be the same since they use same operations the same amount of times

P.S. I use g++ with flag to follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard, that's only one that is turned on in compiler settings

Comment: Seems cache related: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache#Cache_Hits_und_Misses

Comment: _"I am getting ~69 for the first cout and ~172 for the second cout, while I expect them to be the same since they use same operations the same amount of times"_ That's just not how computers work, sorry. They are _far_ more complicated than that. Is there a practical problem here? Do you need it to be faster?

Comment: When asking about runtime performance you must include information on what compiler you used and what flags you passed. Runtime without optimizations turned on is meaningless

Comment: When you try to measure performance, you shouldn't do just one iteration. Do the same task 1000 times, measure total time and divide by 1000. It may be cache issue or your program might have just waited randomly because system scheduler decided  that another task is is more important now.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen They did not do just one iteration.

Comment: What results do you get if you just use `std::swap`? Also; I assume you are timing an optimized build? If not, do that.

Comment: They only do the same amount of operations on the "virtual C++machine" level. Below that, you have an operating system and memories and hierarchies of caches and instruction pipelines and other icky stuff that make reality very complex.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl ~200 and ~265

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Comment: "P.S. I use g++ with flag to follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard, that's only one that is turned on in compiler settings" - You should enable the optimizer with the `-O2` or `-O3` flag as well. Timing unoptimized debug builds is a bit pointless.

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings I need to explain why this happens in a similar case

Comment: So this isn't even the real problem you're asking about?

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Error in question

I am getting **130,000** and **96,000** for first and second respectively.
I think you made a mistake in the order in your question => So the answer in comments were complicated.

## 2 Explanation

If that is the case: **the [2000000][10] array is slower to loop around that the [10][2000000] array**.
It makes much more sense: **in case 2**, the inner loop is **looping over contiguous memory location and this memory (array lines) can be cached** (really cached like L1) and then the memory access are much faster.

## 3 How to advance to an answer

That said: welcome to StackOverflow !
The best way to advance to this kind of answer is to be sure to not regress !

1. Create a reproducible example => Your question is really well made (so I could copy paste)
2. Play around in command line (ex: the C11 flag is not necessary `g++ -O0 array.c && ./a.out` is enough [note the `-O0` to prevent optimization so your code is running]). Dichotomize the code play with `n` and `m`. Comment all what can. Note that the time of the raw loop is exactly the same (64636 tick count for me). If commenting any line (in loop)

```c
for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < m1; j++)
    {
        // int tmp = aa[i][j];
        // aa[i][j] = bb[i][j];
        // bb[i][j] = tmp;
    }
```

Uncomment one memory read (`int tmp = aa[i][j]` meaning REGISTER <- MEMORY meaning reading.

3. Note your result **While playing**:

```
| Array \ Operation | Crude Loop | Read  | Copy  | Full |
| ---               | ---        | ---   | ---   | --- |
| [2000000][10]     | 60083      | 79813 | 79287 | 131311 |
| [10][2000000]     | 54707      | 63893 | 72254 | 100002 |
```

So I get `9.8e-4` ticks per read in the first [2000000][10] array and `4.6e-4` in the second (twice faster).

4. Travel the world with these result to get the answer from.

That is more or less hat you did, and the answer (I repeat) is due to **caching of contiguous memory location in array lines**.